# Entity Framework does not generate association property

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

So.

I'm having trouble fixing this little problem.

I have several classes, and it's all nice and good. Right up until now. I have now added another class (MatchResult), and it works. 
[image: Before]

But when I try to make the correct association:

[image]

It fails with a runtime exception.

Error:

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors:
>
> The relationship 'DbModel.FK_ProductPrice' was not loaded
>   because the type 'DbModel.Product' is not available.
>
> The following information may be useful in resolving the previous
>   error:
>
> The required property 'MatchResults' does not exist on the type
>   'PriceMonitor.Model.Product'.
>
> The relationship 'DbModel.FK_WebshopProduct' was not loaded
>   because the type 'DbModel.Product' is not available.
>
> The following information may be useful in resolving the previous
>   error:
>
> The required property 'MatchResults' does not exist on the type
>   'PriceMonitor.Model.Product'.

It seems - for some reason - that EF does not create the MatchResults property on the Product class.

This approach has worked on every single class I've ever made using EF. Up until now.

Comment: Did you check that the property was actually generated in the code. Can you try forcing code generation?

Comment: How do I force code regeneration?

Comment: Never mind, I found the answer to that :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Apparently, it is a confirmed bug in the Entity Framework. (WHAT?!)

It seems, if you place the .emdx file in a subfolder, automatic code generation does not work.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12256519/entity-framework-issue-in-vs2012-rename-properties-not-sticking).

Comment: Yes, it's a known bug in VS2012 - that's why I asked for forcing code generation...

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error, the name of my csdl, ssdl and msl were not the same als the name of my edmx and contained the name of a other edmx I had within my solution. I changed the connectionstring and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when using EF Database First and the generated POCO classes are not up to date with the edmx file, for example when POCO classes are in a different project than edmx.